# Unable To Merge Dex Error While Running App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to run my android app. It was working fine before. May be after running it in new updated gradle I'm getting this error

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/JdkConstants$CursorType;
```

Tried Cleaning and Rebuilding Project. I get the following error everytime I rebuild and above everytime I run..

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/PROJECT_LOCATION/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [annotations-13.0.jar:org/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow.class]))

My Build Gradle Configuration

```
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "MY_ID"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 65
    versionName "5.5.38"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 14
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience `dexMerger` issues tend to avail themselves when dex versions in your emulator/mobile device fail to seamlessly blend with the newly built ones.

1. Try delete your app on your mobile device/emulator. Then re-install.

Comment: Have you tried ensuring your `build.gradle` dependencies in your app module are consistent i.e you may have two dependencies by a certain vendor 
e.g 
1. 
    `implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'`
    `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1`
These dependencies may depend on each other, however one dependency is newer e.g.27.0.2 than the 27.0.1 causing library compatibility issues.

Try check for lib version warnings in your `build.gradle`